# CSS animation doesn't work in IE and Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, css-animations, microsoft-edge, keyframe

I'm developing some typing animation now.

It works perfect on all browsers except EDGE.

As you can see from the code snippet the cursor should be always visible only at the end of the third row. But on Edge it is visible at the end of each row.

And I guess that my keyframes are not working properly in EDGE.
Pls help.

```css
.css-typing1 p {
  border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}
.css-typing1 p:nth-child(1) {
  width: 18em;
  -webkit-animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing1 p:nth-child(2) {
  width: 18em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.css-typing1 p:nth-child(3) {
  width: 18em;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end);
  animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
  }
}

@keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    /*border: none;*/
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type3 {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    /*border: none;*/
  }
}

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: black }
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    border-right: 0.03em solid black;
  }
  100% {
    border: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="css-typing1">
    <p>
       Some text for row number 1
    </p>
    <p>
       Some text for row number 2
    </p>
    <p>
       Some text for row number 3  
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is IE Edge not recognizing the CSS property `border:none` which you have used in your keyframes. In your code use `border:0` instead of `border:none`.

```css
.css-typing1 p {
      border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      color: black;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0 auto;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-size: 1em;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .css-typing1 p:nth-child(1) {
      width: 18em;
      -webkit-animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end);
      animation: type 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .css-typing1 p:nth-child(2) {
      width: 18em;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end);
      animation: type2 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    .css-typing1 p:nth-child(3) {
      width: 18em;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end);
      animation: type3 1.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite;

      -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
      animation-delay: 3s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }


    @keyframes type2 {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      1% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        border: 0;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes type2 {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      1% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        border: none;
      }
    }

    @keyframes type3 {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      1% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        /*border: none;*/
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes type3 {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      1% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
        /*border: none;*/
      }
    }

    @keyframes blink-caret {
      from, to { border-color: transparent }
      50% { border-color: black }
    }

    @keyframes type {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        border: 0;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes type {
      0% {
        width: 0;
      }
      99.9% {
        border-right: 0.03em solid black;
      }
      100% {
        border: none;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="css-typing1">
        <p>
           Some text for row number 1
        </p>
        <p>
           Some text for row number 2
        </p>
        <p>
           Some text for row number 3  
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Suresh. Just tested it on the last Edge browser. Still the same issue.

Comment: i tested in edge and it is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/5nhu9ogg/5/